# Can I return my Canadian leased Volkswagen car in USA?

Tags: usa, canada, car, lease

I have Volkswagen car lease in Canada, which should finish soon. But now I live and work in US. Can I return car here to VW or I should go to Canada?

Actually I asked in VW dealership, but they said to call to VW, I tried to call, but it's too long to wait when somebody replied.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that it would be possible given the miles vs. kilometers difference.

Comment: I suppose so, but I'd like to get some confirmation.

Comment: Does the lease contract say anything about how and where to return the car?

Comment: I need to check

Comment: Did you ask VW if you could take the car out the country? Seeing as it's a lease (and not yours) they may have particular rules around this (and if you did ask, that might have been the time to ask what to do when the lease ends).

Comment: why should I ask? I lease it and can drive everywhere where I want.

Comment: No you can't it's VW's car.  From the US border site: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/248/~/taking-%2F-bringing-a-car-%2F-vehicle-into-or-out-of-the-u.s.-that-belongs-to-a "If the car or vehicle is leased, the driver should have written permission from the rental company to drive the car in another country".  In this case VW is the renter.

Comment: How did you get insurance in Canada for the car, or did you think your US insurance will cover you in Canada long term as well?

Comment: I have Canadian insurance and it's cover when it's in US,

Comment: Ah, no that's for day trips/holidays.  You can't use that long term.  You should have imported the vehicle, see here: https://www.cbp.gov/trade/basic-import-export/personal-vehicle - except it's not your personal vehicle, it's VWs.

Comment: no, I asked insurance, it's not for day trip, they said month is okay, and every moth I drive back to Canada. I not imported car, I'm still Canadian resident and have Canadian driver licence and Canadian car.

Comment: Ah, no that's playing the slippery eel.  You are doing a temporary trip every month.  Do they know you actually live in the US?

Comment: I take it you tell the border guys you are only going on a trip as well every time?

Comment: Who know? I have 2 residences now: Canada and US.

Comment: Well if VW find out, they can likely do you for theft of their car, so I'd just take it back on your next trip back to Canada and hand it back, do it asap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42180/discussion-between-alex-and-the-wandering-dev-manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is, no, you cannot. The car may or may not be in the US illegally to begin with; certainly VW would have something to say about it if they were made aware of it, which they definitely would be if you tried to return it in the US. Your insurance situation is also probably tenuous at best.

You should return the car in Canada and then if you intend to continue residing in the US (which is what you are doing; it sounds like you are only spending a minimal amount of days each month in Canada, and the US considers you to be a resident if you spend only about half the year here, let alone nearly all of it) then get a US-based car and US insurance.

Assuming you don't get deported.